# draw grid of squares with several colormaps

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a 100x100 grid, I have z values that are integers `[0,4]`.  I can plot them with a

```
use_cmap= matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(cmap_name, colors, N=numberOfStates)
PL.pcolor(config, vmin = 0, vmax = numberOfStates - 1, cmap = use_cmap)
```

That works out fine, pylab (matplotlib?) interpolates those five possible values against the spectrum of colors I gave it.

But I have a complication to add. The 100x100 grid is divided into arbitrary polygons (*voronoi* cells) (a point's membership defined by which of ten arbitrary points are that points nearest neighbor).  I want a different colormap for each of those polygons/*voronoi* cells.

For example if there were three *voronoi* cells on the grid,  in cell 0,  a `z=0` is light green, ..., `z=3` is medium,  `z=4` is dark green.  In cell 1,  the `z`'s will be shades of purple, and cell 3, shades of orange.

Looking for a decent way to implement this.

============================

@Tom gave me the important tip -- pcolor accepts 'masked arrays'

A small test worked perfectly.

```
import pylab as PL

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma


def draw():
    plt.cla()


    #use_cmap = PL.cm.binary
    #use_cmap = PL.cm.seismic
    #use_cmap = PL.cm.PuBu

    config = np.array([range(0,5), range(3,8), range(5,10) ])


    t = [True]*5
    f = [False]*5

    blue_mask = [True]*5
    #print "\tblue_mask = t\n{0}".format(blue_mask)
    blue_mask.extend(f)
    #print "\tblue_mask.extend(f)\n{0}".format(blue_mask)
    blue_mask.extend(t)
    #print "\tblue_mask.extend(t)\n{0}".format(blue_mask)

    blue_mask = ma.masked_array(config, blue_mask)

    orange_mask = [False]*5
    orange_mask.extend(t)
    orange_mask.extend(f)
    orange_mask = ma.masked_array(config, orange_mask)

    print "blue mask:\n{0}".format(blue_mask)
    print "\norange_mask:\n{0}".format(orange_mask)    


    plt.pcolor(blue_mask, vmin = 0, vmax = 10 - 1, cmap = 'Blues') #'Oranges'
    plt.pcolor(orange_mask, vmin = 0, vmax = 10 - 1, cmap = 'Oranges') #'Oranges'

    plt.axis('image')
    plt.title('t = sometime' )
    plt.show()

draw()
```

Comment: For each of your polygons, use `numpy` masked arrays to mask out regions that are not in that polygon, then use `pcolor` for each of your masked arrays, with the appropriate colormap.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: @tom yeah, that looks promising. Thanks